# How can I troubleshoot 'invalid initialization of reference' error while building a ROS2 package with Colcon?

Tags: ros2, colcon

I'm trying to build a package of ROS2 Galactic.

After I installed all the files and at last I tried to type "Colcon Build".

But there is an error message like followings and it is failed to build:

chiwan@Masterarbeit:~/tello_ros_ws$ colcon build

Starting >>> tello_msgs
Starting >>> ros2_shared Starting >>> tello_description Finished <<< ros2_shared [0.59s]                                    Finished <<< tello_description [0.74s]                              Finished <<< tello_msgs [1.36s]                      Starting >>> tello_driver Starting >>> tello_gazebo Finished <<< tello_driver [0.64s]                                      stderr: tello_gazebo                                In file included from /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/flight_data.hpp:9, from /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/src/tello-ros2-gazebo/tello_ros/tello_gazebo/src/tello_plugin.cpp:8: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp: In function ‘void rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(const FlightData&, std::ostream&, size_t)’: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:32:17: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const FlightData&’ {aka ‘const tello_msgs::msg::FlightData_std::allocator<void >&’} from expression of type ‘const *header_type’ {aka ‘const std_msgs::msg::Header*std::allocator<void >’} 32 |     to_yaml(msg.header, out, indentation + 2);
|             ~~~~^~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:23:39: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(const FlightData&, std::ostream&, size_t)’ 23 |   const tello_msgs::msg::FlightData & msg,
|   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:41:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 41 |     value_to_yaml(msg.raw, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:51:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 51 |     value_to_yaml(msg.sdk, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:61:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 61 |     value_to_yaml(msg.pitch, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:71:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 71 |     value_to_yaml(msg.roll, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:81:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 81 |     value_to_yaml(msg.yaw, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:91:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 91 |     value_to_yaml(msg.vgx, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:101:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 101 |     value_to_yaml(msg.vgy, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:111:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 111 |     value_to_yaml(msg.vgz, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:121:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 121 |     value_to_yaml(msg.templ, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:131:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 131 |     value_to_yaml(msg.temph, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:141:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 141 |     value_to_yaml(msg.tof, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:151:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 151 |     value_to_yaml(msg.h, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:161:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 161 |     value_to_yaml(msg.bat, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:171:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 171 |     value_to_yaml(msg.baro, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:181:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 181 |     value_to_yaml(msg.time, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:191:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 191 |     value_to_yaml(msg.agx, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:201:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 201 |     value_to_yaml(msg.agy, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:211:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 211 |     value_to_yaml(msg.agz, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:221:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 221 |     value_to_yaml(msg.mid, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:231:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 231 |     value_to_yaml(msg.x, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:241:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 241 |     value_to_yaml(msg.y, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/flight_data__traits.hpp:251:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 251 |     value_to_yaml(msg.z, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/tello_response.hpp:9, from /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/src/tello-ros2-gazebo/tello_ros/tello_gazebo/src/tello_plugin.cpp:9: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/tello_response__traits.hpp: In function ‘void rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(const TelloResponse&, std::ostream&, size_t)’: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/tello_response__traits.hpp:28:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 28 |     value_to_yaml(msg.rc, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/msg/detail/tello_response__traits.hpp:38:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 38 |     value_to_yaml(msg.str, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/srv/tello_action.hpp:9, from /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/src/tello-ros2-gazebo/tello_ros/tello_gazebo/src/tello_plugin.cpp:10: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/srv/detail/tello_action__traits.hpp: In function ‘void rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(const TelloAction_Request&, std::ostream&, size_t)’: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/srv/detail/tello_action__traits.hpp:28:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 28 |     value_to_yaml(msg.cmd, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/srv/detail/tello_action__traits.hpp: In function ‘void rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(const TelloAction_Response&, std::ostream&, size_t)’: /home/chiwan/tello_ros_ws/install/tello_msgs/include/tello_msgs/srv/detail/tello_action__traits.hpp:79:5: error: ‘value_to_yaml’ was not declared in this scope 79 |     value_to_yaml(msg.rc, out);
|     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TelloPlugin.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/TelloPlugin.dir/src/tello_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/TelloPlugin.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
--- Failed   <<< tello_gazebo [15.9s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 4 packages finished [17.7s] 1 package failed: tello_gazebo 1 package had stderr output: tello_gazebo

How should I fix it and what is the reason of this error?